# Latebinding issue for object

Tags: vb.net

Following code causes an error at `oDataObject.lastError` and `oDataObject.clearerror()` of object ,while setting the `option strict On` a late binding issue persists.
Before `option strict` set to `on` the  `oDataObject.lastError` and `oDataObject.clearerror()` showing as inbuild function and  supports all class.

```
If Not trySettingValue(moProp, oDataObject, oTB.Text, sError) Then
        oTB.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        bOk = False
Else
        oTB.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
End If
```

---

```
 Public Shared Function trySettingValue(ByRef oProp As 
     System.Reflection.PropertyInfo, _
    ByRef oDataObject As Object, _
    ByVal oValue As Object, _
    ByRef sError As String) As Boolean
    Try
        oDataObject.clearerror()
        Select Case oProp.PropertyType.FullName

            Case "System.String"
                Dim str As String
                str = CType(oValue, String)
                oProp.SetValue(oDataObject, str, Nothing)
            Case Else
        End Select
        ' errorhandling  
        If oDataObject.lastError <> "" Then
            sError = sError & oDataObject.lastError
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    Catch e As System.Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Message)
        Trace.Flush()
        sError = sError & "De ingevoerde waarde voor '" & oProp.Name & "' is foutief." & vbCrLf
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: What is `oDataObject`? You can't use `oDataObject.lastError` if `oDataObject` is declared as object and not casted to it's real type that has a `lastError` property. Probably better than casting here was to pass the correct type, so change the signature of the method. Maybe generics are an option too, then no casting was needed.

Comment: oDataObject is always pass as a byref object

Comment: Private Sub dgrKostendrager_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgrKostendrager.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
            Dim btnTemp As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnSelecteer"), Button)
            btnTemp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "doSelect('" & e.Item.DataItem("KOSTL") & "','" & Replace(e.Item.DataItem("KLTXT"), "'", "\'") & "'); return false;")
        End If
    End Sub